# Problem to show Number

Tags: qgis

I need to show normal number this problem appear when number more than 6 number like 1000000

[image: I need to show normal number]

Comment: this a solution but if i need to show it in qgis itself as a visible number. How Can WE fix This Problem ?

Comment: Using the processing plugin basic statistics return the requested behaviour. It is however less flexible than the panel,

Comment: What you require would probably require modifying python files (qgsstatisticalsummarydockwidget.cpp?) and re-compiling qgis.

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of the Statistics Panel, there is a small icon `"Copy Statistics to Clipboard"`.

Click on this icon and paste the clipboard to a spreadsheet (e.g. Excel).
You can see the details and also change the exponential notation to the standard notation.

[image]